# Backbone - Check if Record Already Exists - Is there a better way than this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In Backbone, I need to check if a model record already exists.  Right now, I am doing it by fetching the model by id, and seeing if its "created_at" attribute is undefined.  This feels brittle to me.  Does anyone have any better recommendations?

```
var dealProgram = new WhiteDeals.Models.DealProgram({id: servant_id});
      dealProgram.fetch({
        success: function() {
          var program = dealProgram.toJSON();
          var datecheck = program.created_at
          if(typeof datecheck === 'undefined'){
              dealPrograms.create({
                title: "", 
                servant_id: servant.servant_id,
                servant_name: servant.name,
                servant_master: servant.master
              }, 
              {
                success: function () {
                  self.manageServants(servants);
                }
              }); // End of dealPrograms.create
          } else if (datecheck !== undefined) {
              console.log("is defined, success!")
              self.manageServants(servants);
          }; // End of if statement for non-existant dealPrograms
        } // End of success
      }); // End of dealProgram.fetch
```

Comment: Do you have a collection those models client-side? Are you checking for their existence in your DB? ... a little bit more information please.

Comment: The collection is stored server-side, and I am checking for their existence in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

You'll obviously have to check by using a request (whatever the form of the request, you'll have a low amount of data anyway). Guess you should still wonder if it wouldn't be worth fetching all your models at once in a collection so you can make the check client-side (or only the id if it'd be too big to fetch everything).